# How to view hardware video encoder/decoder utilization on AMD GPUs?

Tags: amd-graphics, codecs, monitoring, hardware-acceleration

For a long time I've used the tool `psensor` to view the utilization of the hardware video encoding/decoding block on my Nvidia GPUs, but recently I've been curious about how to perform a similar task on my AMD laptop. I've tried the `radeontop` utility, but it does not report this statistic. If it matters, my GPU is part of the Raven Ridge family.